# ON_ERROR parameter does not work for me with JSON files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created simple table in Snowflake:

```
Column name    Type
S              VARCHAR
N              NUMBER
```

Both columns are nullable. 
Now I want to load partially bad result into the table from `CSV` and `JSON` files.

CSV

```
s, n
hello, 1
bye, 2
nothing, zero
```

Third line is "bad": its second element it not a number. 
Command that I use to load this file:

```
"COPY INTO "DEMO_DB"."PUBLIC"."TEST5" FROM @my_s3_stage1 files=('2good-1bad.csv') file_format = (type = csv field_delimiter = ',' skip_header = 1) ON_ERROR = CONTINUE;
```

Thrown `SnowflakeSQLException`:

```
errorCode = 200038 
SQLState = 0A000 
message: Cannot convert value in the driver from type:12 to type:int, value=PARTIALLY_LOADED.
```

Two "good" lines are written into table; the "bad" one is ignored. This result is expected.

However when I am using the following JSON lines file:

```
{"s":"hello", "n":1}
{"s":"bye", "n":2}
{"s":"nothing", "n":"zero"}
```

with this command:

```
COPY INTO "DEMO_DB"."PUBLIC"."TEST5" FROM @my_s3_stage1 files=('2good-1bad.json') file_format = (type = json) 
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME=CASE_INSENSITIVE 
ON_ERROR = CONTINUE
```

I get the following `SnowflakeSQLException`:

```
errorCode = 100071 
SQLState = 22000 
message: Failed to cast variant value "zero" to FIXED
```

and nothing is written to the DB.

The question is "What's wrong?"
Why `ON_ERROR = CONTINUE` does not work with my JSON file?

PS:

1. wrapping `CONTINUE` with single quotes does not help
2. using lower case does not help
3. actually I do not need CONTINUE, I need `SKIP_FILE_<num>`, however this does not work with JSON as well.
4. actually we are using avro in production environment, so it is more relevant. I am using `JSON` for tests because it is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that on_error is not supported with non-CSV file formats. I've seen folks with files who can workaround specifying CSV file type with FIELD_DELIMITER = 'none'.

I have seen a couple folks request that this option work for semi-structured files and you are welcome to submit a feature request as well to create more demand for it:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

The documentation doesn't really spell it out that it's not supported (feel free to submit docs feedback using the button at the bottom), but you can see it hinted at:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

"You can use the corresponding file format (e.g. JSON), but any error in the transformation will stop the COPY operation, even if you set the ON_ERROR option to continue or skip the file."